# what is this error mean when convert from java code with generic to kotlin, single ban after the T?

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

trying to convert some java code to kotlin, and having problem with the ones with generic type.

one sample here is the java code from Danny Preussler’s post Of Bundles and ViewModels:
[here](https://proandroiddev.com/customizing-the-new-viewmodel-cf28b8a7c5fc)

```
class BundleAwareViewModelFactory<T extends ParcelableViewModel> implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private final Bundle bundle;
    private final ViewModelProvider.Factory provider;
    public BundleAwareViewModelFactory(@Nullable Bundle bundle,
                                   ViewModelProvider.Factory provider) {
        this.bundle = bundle;
        this.provider = provider;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public T create(final Class modelClass) {
        T viewModel = (T) provider.create(modelClass);
        if (bundle != null) {
            viewModel.readFrom(bundle);
        }
        return viewModel;
    }
}

public abstract class ParcelableViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public abstract void writeTo(@NonNull Bundle bundle);
    public abstract void readFrom(@NonNull Bundle bundle);
}
```

trying to convert the code snippet into kotlin code, not be able do it right so using the android studio IDE to do it and get this result, still it shows compiler error:

Error:(24, 1) Class 'BundleAwareViewModelFactory' must be declared abstract or implement abstract member public abstract fun  create(p0: Class!): T! defined in android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory

Error:(28, 34) Type parameter bound for T in fun  create(p0: Class!): T!
 is not satisfied: inferred type CapturedTypeConstructor(*) is not a subtype of ViewModel!

```
class BundleAwareViewModelFactory<T : ParcelableViewModel>(@param:Nullable private val bundle: Bundle?, 
                                                                private val provider: ViewModelProvider.Factory) : 
        ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun create(modelClass: Class<*>): T {
        val viewModel = provider.create(modelClass) as T
        if (bundle != null) {
            viewModel.readFrom(bundle)
        }
        return viewModel
    }
}

abstract class ParcelableViewModel : ViewModel() {

    abstract fun writeTo(bundle: Bundle)
    abstract fun readFrom(bundle: Bundle)
}
```

what does the single ban T! mean?
what does the error means or how those generic to be presented in the kotlin, or any post talks about the generic in kotlin?

Comment: The single bang signifies a platform type in kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types

Comment: Google recommends never let ViewModel to know about Android classes, it's a bad practice. I'm pretty sure there are better ways to do that without mixing it up. You can use ViewModel and still use onSaveInstanceState() and onCreate() to restore whatever you need. Letting the heavy stuff into ViewModel.

Comment: Is that approach recreating the ViewModel every time activity is recreated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got a working version, but not sure how it could be made better:

```
class BundleAwareViewModelFactory<T : ParcelableViewModel>(private val bundle: Bundle?,
                                                       private val provider: 
ViewModelProvider.Factory) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
override fun <T : ViewModel>create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    val viewModel : T = provider.create(modelClass) as T

    if (bundle != null && viewModel is ParcelableViewModel) {
        viewModel.readFrom(bundle)
    }
    return viewModel
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`T!` is a platform type. What it means is that, Kotlin isn't aware of how the final value will turn out to be, whether null or not so it leaves it to you to decide. For your code, try this.

```
class BundleAwareViewModelFactory<T : ParcelableViewModel>(bundle:Bundle?,
                                                                    provider:ViewModelProvider.Factory):ViewModelProvider.Factory {
  private val bundle:Bundle?
  private val provider:ViewModelProvider.Factory
  init{
    this.bundle = bundle
    this.provider = provider
  }
  override fun create(modelClass:Class<*>):T {
    val viewModel = provider.create(modelClass) as T
    if (bundle != null)
    {
      viewModel.readFrom(bundle)
    }
    return viewModel
  }
}
abstract class ParcelableViewModel:ViewModel() {
  abstract fun writeTo(@NonNull bundle:Bundle)
  abstract fun readFrom(@NonNull bundle:Bundle)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alf! The code of yours got similar error:  Error:(32, 1) Class 'BundleAwareViewModelFactory' must be declared abstract or implement abstract member public abstract fun <T : ViewModel!> create(p0: Class<T!>!): T! defined in android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory
Error:(40, 5) 'create' overrides nothing
Error:(41, 34) Type parameter bound for T in fun <T : ViewModel!> create(p0: Class<T!>!): T!
 is not satisfied: inferred type CapturedTypeConstructor(*) is not a subtype of ViewModel!